# Prove that $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \text{arccot}^{2} (\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-x)$ has a bound for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \text{arccot}^{2} (\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-x)$. I need to prove that it is bounded by a universal constant not depending on $N$ or $x$. I could consider an integral on $\int_{0}^{\infty}$, but i guess it's couldn't be represented as elementary functions. Also I thought that this function is periodic (depending of $x$) and so it could be bounded.

But maybe there is a better way to show the bound ?

Comment: @Winther how to show that bounded by $\pi^{2} / 4$?

Comment: But what about $\sqrt{n^{2}+n+1}$ term ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I just want to prove that for $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$ this sum is bounded by some constant (which doesn't depend of $N$).

Comment: @openspace: is the wanted constant allowed to depend on $x$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I guess no. Actually that's part of Dirichlet's test for $\displaystyle \sum \frac{arcctg^{2}(\sqrt{n^{2}+n+1}-x)}{\sqrt{n}}$, so I need to prove that particular sum is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\arctan^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-x}\leq\sum_{n\geq 1}\min\left[\frac{\pi^2}{4},\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-x\right)^2}\right] $$
and for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there are at most $2$ values of $n\geq 1$ such that $\left|\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-x\right|\leq\frac{2}{\pi}$.
 By excluding these terms (if existing), the contribution provided by the remaining terms is bounded by $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$, hence
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\arctan^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-x}\leq \frac{5\pi^2}{6}$$
holds. It is a pretty crude inequality, but it does the job.

Comment: I guess there should be $max$?

Comment: @openspace: no no, it is a min. $\arctan^2(x)$ is simultaneously bounded by $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$ and $x^2$, so by their minimum.

Comment: And we take $\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n^{2}+n+1}-x)^{2}}$, because of Taylor representation?

Comment: @openspace: we consider $\arctan^2(z)\leq z^2$ then replace $z$ with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-x}$.

Comment: And why we get $\frac{5\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: @openspace: we have at most two "ugly" terms giving a contribute $\leq 2\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{4}$, the remaining terms give a contribute $\leq \frac{\pi^2}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{6}$.